# C++ Change image based on a click (Visual Studio C++)

Tags: visual-studio, image, c++-cli

In visual studio, when making a C++ windows application form. I want a picture to change when I click on it.

So when I double click the picture and it brings up the click action script, what script do I use.....

Similiar to

```
 int temp = System::Int32::Parse(label1->Text);
 temp++; label1->Text =
 temp.ToString();
```

Which just increments an integer in a label

Comment: I've got a very strong suspicion that you are not programming in C++, from your code snippet. It looks more like C#

Comment: Hi there, I was pretty sure that I am programming in C++.......but I'm by far an expert (as you can tell by my question)

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio, I've gone "open new project", in program type, gone to "other languages", scrolled past c# to c++, and started my new project with c++.......added a basic label with value 0, doulbe clicked it and added that code......

......is it possible that the code works in both languages?

If so, my original question remains.....(if not I need to fix something about how I'm starting a project)

Answer (score 1):

```
PicutreBox1.OnClick += PictureBox1_Click(PictureBox1,System.Events.OnClick)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
private void PictureBox1_Click(object^ sender, Events^ e)
{
  PictureBox1->Image=Image.FromFile(@"YourFolderPath/image.jpg")
}
```