# Visual Studio Image type is not allowed

Tags: c++, image, visual-studio, visual-c++, c++-cli

I'm trying to change image based on a click (Visual Studio C++).
My code:

```
private: System::Void FirstChannelButton_Click_1(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    FirstChannelButton->Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\Username\source\repos\Project\ChOne.png");
}
```

Really the same thing that the person tried to do here
[C++ Change image based on a click (Visual Studio C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190647/c-change-image-based-on-a-click-visual-studio-c)

But i get error: type name is not allowed and 'System::Drawing::Image': illegal use of this type as an expression.

Comment: Is this in a C++/CLI project? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI

Comment: @RetiredNinja yes it is

Comment: `FromFile` is a static method so you have to use `::` when you call it: `Image::FromFile("...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FromFile` is a static method and C++ /CLI syntax requires to use `::` for static method calls. So in this case the call should look next:

```
FirstChannelButton->Image = Image::FromFile("...")
```